# Animated show about people being able to summon monsters from gauntlets with magic

Tags: story-identification, anime, magic

I remember watching a show when I was younger, it came out before 2018. The main character pulled out an ancient gauntlet from a stone. With gauntlets you could summon monsters to fight each other. The main character was a cleaner for a stadium or an arena. As I seem to remember he was working for an older person, his uncle I think.

Comment: Summon monsters from a gauntlet... Kaijudo? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaijudo

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is Battle Claw because he pulls an ancient gauntlet out of stone. Fights with monsters and worked at a stadium.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).